# imagemagick no output

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL) ;
$orig = "original.jpg";
$out = "output.jpg";
$cmd = "-sepia-tone 90%";
exec("/usr/bin/convert $orig $cmd $out ");
?>
```

After I run this, I expected a sepia toned version of original.jpg named output.jpg. when I check the directory, output.jpg doesnt exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: even with error_reporting(E_ALL) you may also find some errors are suppressed by your php.ini configuration.

Comment: What is supposed to happen? you don't see the file created? Have you tried echoing the command and run it outside of PHP?

Comment: @MathieuImbert - I expected a sepia toned version of original.jpg named output.jpg. when I check the directory, output.jpg doesnt exist. (thanks for pointing that out. Edited my post)

Comment: Double check permissions. Make sure the user running the script has write privileges to the directory (and/or file if it already exists). If this is run on cli, it is most likely whomever is running the script, if this is called by webserver, it is most likely apache (or whomever the webserver is run under). Also make sure that the user has +x on /usr/bin/convert

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - changed dir persmissions (recursed into subdirectories) to 777; does that mean anything?

Comment: @bigapple does it work? also, maybe pass in an empty variable to the second parameter of exec. this will get you any output. then print_r that. If there is an error with /usr/bin/convert you would get the output of that error here.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Like so? 

exec("/usr/bin/convert $orig $cmd $out ",$err);
print_r($err);

no output.

Comment: @bigapple is this run through a webserver (such as apache, nginx) or command line?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Run through Apache.

Answer (score 1):

`<? php` should be `<?php`.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious if that was just a typo... but you beat me to pointing it out while I was debating that. : )
Well played!